# limit inside of an infinite sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to solve this expression? 
\begin{equation}
2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}-\frac{n^{2}(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{3}}\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\frac{np^{2}+n2p+2}{e^{np}}=?
\end{equation}
This expression tends to zero 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\frac{np^{2}+n2p+2}{e^{np}}=0
\end{equation*}
But then I do not know how to proceed

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you provide the steps before you get the sum you wrote? The issue is probably before what you provide.

Comment: Yes, I just include it

Comment: why do you think you can integrate the infinite series term by term? Is there a radius of convergence to think about?

Comment: Oh, then my mistake comes from solving the integral separately. How should I proceed otherwise? This type of problem is new to me

Comment: You are simply looking at $0+0+0+\cdots = 0.$ Unless you mean to ask something else ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is independent of the index of summation in this case. So you need to show the limit of the sum:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{k\to \infty}2\sum^{k}_{n=1}-\frac{n^{2}(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{3}}\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\frac{np^{2}+n2p+2}{e^{np}}=\lim_{k\to \infty}2\sum^{k}_{n=1}-\frac{n^{2}(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{3}} \cdot 0
\end{equation}

Since each partial sum is zero, the entire sum is zero.

Comment: I thought the same, but the result should theoretically be \ frac {\ pi^{2}}{3}. I have uploaded the steps of the proof

Comment: @HectorManuelGarridoHenrquez I was referring to your infinite sum. The variance of the logistic distribution is obviously not zero. you're effectively asking another question in your post.

Comment: I think you're right. In the terms that asked the question, your answer is correct. I will formulate the question correctly in another post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dominated convergence theorem to interchange the sum and limit, and then evaluate the sum and then take the limit of that value

Comment: This is offtopic, no?